# pass object as value C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I am passing an object: `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement` to a method when navigating WebBrowser object to a URL in C#, but if I navigate the WebBrowser object to another page, the HtmlElement object becomes null. The pseudo-code is:

```
//Code to navigate to a page
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

//pass one of the page's element as parameter in a method
Method(HtmlElement WebBrowser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("input")["search"]);

Method(HtmlElement Element)
{
  //Works fine till now
  MessageBox.Show(Element.InnerText);

  //Code to navigate to another page
  WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.different_page.com");

  //Here the Element object throws exception because it becomes null after another navigation to another website.
  MessageBox.Show(Element.InnerText); 
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing HtmlElement is losing reference because WebBrowser.Document changes once .Navigate gets called. Try storing Element.InnerText in a string variable just before the .Navigate

Comment: yes, this could be the possible reason for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around to the problem. The solution is to create a temporary WebBrowser object and pass the Element in it as OuterHtml directly into the body, and then navigate to that DOM text as if it was a response HTML of a page:

```
Method(HtmlElement Element)
{
  MessageBox.Show(Element.InnerText);

  WebBrowser WebBrowser = new WebBrowser();

  WebBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><head></head><body>" + Element.OuterHtml + "</body></html>";

  while (WebBrowserReadyState.Complete != WebBrowser.ReadyState)
            Application.DoEvents();

  MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText);
}
```

Now I am able to access the Element as: `WebBrowser.Document.Body`And it persists even if I navigate the original WebBrowser object to another page.

Comment: +1 because it does the job without too much of a coding effort.

Answer (score 4):

`Element` is holding a reference, therefore it loses its state on the second navigation. Try storing value types (such as `.InnerText`) before executing the second navigation.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted other properties also, like GetAttribute. I have posted answer to my problem.